# How can I detect that microphone doesn't support certain rate (e.g. 44Hz)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, microphone

[Adobe's documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#rate) denotes that user's microphone may not support all the standard rates (5, 8, 11, 22, 44).

I want to choose rate 22kHz if 44 isn't supported. Is there a way to detect in my code that 44kHz rate isn't supported?

Comment: Which codec are you using to compress the sound?

Comment: I record raw PCM without compression.